# Why Citroën is the most Euro?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Excerpted from [bloomberg.com](http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-09-22/the-sting-of-volkswagen-s-slap-across-my-well-moisturized-euro-loving-face):

> When I decided I wanted to buy a car, I had the Sportwagen TDI at the top of my list. Over the weeks and months in which I drove every Honda, Toyota, Ford, and Hyundai under the sun, it never fell from that position. It was, I thought, the perfect car for a poncy Europhile such as myself: a German (Euro!) station wagon (so Euro!) with a diesel engine (Eurissimo!). *The only thing more Euro would be a Citroën that ran on adultery.*

What does the last statement mean? I mean why is Citroën the most Euro? Why he says it ran on adultery?

Comment: He doesn't say it runs on adultery, he says that a Citroen that ran on adultery would be more Euro.  There's kind of an implied "if": it *would* be more Euro *if* it ran on adultery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very droll.

It reflects the attitudes of himself as an American toward Europeans: maybe other Americans will find it funny. He thinks that

- station wagons are more European than American (false)
- Europeans worry more about global warming than Americans, and so prefer diesel cars (probably true),
- the French (Citroen is a French brand) are more European than the Germans (possibly true),
- all French men have a mistress (adultery- exaggerated, but there is a little truth in the idea).

Comment: I don't think "station wagon" is used in the US much anymore (beyond really old ones >20 years). Most larger autos nowadays are called SUVs.

Comment: You are spot on with 20 years, @user3169, but station wagon seems to still be going strong according to NGram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=station+wagon%3Aeng_us_2009%2C+station+wagon%3Aeng_gb_2009&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstation%20wagon%3Aeng_us_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstation%20wagon%3Aeng_gb_2009%3B%2Cc0. The term never really caught on in the UK: we talk about estate cars. You might find this article interesting: http://jalopnik.com/5872197/why-is-it-called-a-station-wagon

Comment: The prevalence of diesel cars in Europe was not originally due to concerns for Global Warming but rather the price of petrol in Europe, diesel used to be cheaper, but then the oil companies caught on...  Definitely the allusion with Citroen is to the French and their mistresses and the Citroen and would be considered more European than German cars since Citroen are not sold in the US (scarcity factor).